# How to capture a $scope object with multiple objects from web api

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, object, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass a object which has multiple objects inside it as below

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
ProductID
:
"50"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
BrandID
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
BrandID
:
26
__proto__
:
Object
3
:
Object
BrandID
:
20
__proto__
:
Object
```

One of these objects has different key value pair than the others. How can I get capture this data from a Web Api controller. How should I modify my Model in the Web Api project.

Comment: It would be better to show json here, because showed data structure is unclear.

Comment: the json should be

`object=[{ProductID:"50"},{BrandID:"24"},{BrandID:"26"},{BrandID:"20"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the array you are trying to send to Web API contains different objects with different schemas. This approach is certainly error prone, and will not allow you to use `ModelBinding` properly.

Why don't you change the format of your object to something like this?

```
$scope.myObject = {
    ProductID: 50,
    BrandIDs: [24, 26, 20]
};
```

Using this kind of object you will be able to bind it to a strongly typed model in Web API.

```
public class MyModel {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public List<int> BrandIDs { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult Post(MyModel model) {
    var productId = model.ProductID;
    foreach(var brandId in model.BrandIDs) {
        DoSomething(brandId);
    }
    return Ok();    
}
```

Comment: I was killing my self to get a scope object like that to pass. But couldn't do that

Comment: May you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a class model that corresponds to you JSON and Web Api will automatically bind it. It seems that what you are passing is an array, so you can do something like that:

```
public void Execute(Model[] input)
{

}

....

public class Model
{
    public int? ProductId {get;set;}
    public int? BrandId {get;set;}
}
```

Or if you want one object with an array inside you can pass a class like that

```
public class ProductsContainer
{
     public Product[] Products {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Since I'm passing multiple BrandIDs would this model be OK to use. ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by multiple BrandIds, if you mean multiple objects each of them containing a BrandId, then yes it will be totally fine.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, please don't forget to accept the answer if you liked it :)